# Does Dr No have all his fingers?

Tags: character, james-bond, dr-no

A friend is going as Dr No for his Christmas party, and wants to make sure he gets all the finer details down.

> I decided to go the whole hog and have built myself a surprisingly
>   accurate Dr. No radiation suit (photos to follow).
>
> But, I'm stuck on a finer detail. Does he have all 5 fingers on both
>   hands in the movie? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_No suggests
>   yes, but I thought one hand was more crippled that the other?

Can anyone provide definitive evidence of the state of his fingers in the movie?

And are there any other key distinguishing features that he needs to ensure he has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the images on Google for "Doctor No", you'll see that his hand does have 5 fingers (he wouldn't be able to hold his cigar without a thumb in the screenshots):

[image: Picture 1 [1]]

A closer look:
[image]

The crippling was the fact that he was caught in an explosion and that his hand is an artificial hand - it can't feel like a regular hand, but it IS capable of crushing a small metal statuette (not sure if your friend can get a similar artificial hand!)

About the only other thing I can think of would be the suit, which is similar to one 
Bond himself wears [3] when he's a prisoner of Dr. No.